# In docker using DB2, connecting to testdb(which is catalog at node) causes out of memory error

Tags: docker, memory, db2

I've been using db2 image from https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2
and after setting up the container running in docker.
Then I increase INSTANCE_MEMROY and member memory by:
db2 update dbm cfg using INSTANCE_MEMORY 508241 immediate
db2 update dbm cfg member 0 using instance_memory 508241 immediate
The reason I set 508241 is that if I set 508241, then db2start will throw an error:
*12/22/2021 13:22:38     0   0   SQL1220N  The database manager failed to allocate shared memory.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019*
So I had to use the number 508241 for INSTANCE_MEMORY and member memory.

After db2start successfully run, db2 connect to testdb user db2inst1 user somepassword, error will show up:
SQL1224N  The database manager is not able to accept new requests, has
terminated all requests in progress, or has terminated the specified request
because of an error or a forced interrupt.  SQLSTATE=55032

Questions:

1. What should I do next to get it right when connect to testdb?
2. How could I set more than 508241 for INSTANCE_MEMORY and get it right when running db2start?

By the way, testdb is created using:
catalog tcpip node somenode remote somehost server 50000
catalog databse testdb as testdb at node somenode

Comment: Have you checked db2diag.log? What does it state? Do you use the Db2 Community Edition which is restricted to 16 GB memory? Provide more details

Comment: Hi, I'm using DB2 community edition image in docker hub.
I've checked db2diag.log and I even set docker for mac with 16G memory, when connect that database which is at node, then the memory will all be consumed, and it will show some OOM error .

Comment: Is this OOM error relative to the version of docker desktop for mac?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the host operating system detail and version,  and what hardware resources are available,  and how much allocated to docker, and docker info details.